# Azure DevOps: Is it not possible to use wildcard when searching for a string?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to search for a string with wildcard. I checked Microsoft documentation and it gives an example that I should be able to use '?' symbol in the middle of search query as a wildcard:

> Add wildcard characters, * and ?, to keywords to extend the search
> criteria.

> alpha?version finds instances of alpha1version and alphaXversion.

The example of what I'm looking for e.g.

```
"api/testEndpoint/{id}/testResource"
```

I need to be able to wildcard `{id}` part because it can be named differently to what I expect given it is used across multiple microservices.

What I've tried so far is:

```
"api/testEndpoint/?/testResource"
"api/testEndpoint/*/testResource"
"api/testEndpoint/????/testResource"
```

The last attempt was to test if I can find anything at all using this search, thought that perhaps single '?' is replacing just one character so it means that it should've found `"api/testEndpoint/{id}/testResource"` because it finds it if I search for exact match, however, none of the attempts returned any results.

Is there a way to perform this kind of search in Azure DevOps at all or I'm missing something?